# docker blockio can not monitor when using dd to test

Tags: docker, lxc

I have a container running on my host. there is a volume I bind to the container.
`"Volumes": {
        "/data/mcluster_data": "/data/mcluster_data/d-mcl-30_struc_test",
        "/srv/mcluster": "/srv/docker/vfs/dir/2f1b1f1b9fd7c35132d42ee3896215771956a763929474fc7493cb97270a781c"
    },`
the path `/srv/mcluster` is binded to a path on the host `/srv/docker/vfs/dir/2f1b1f1b9fd7c35132d42ee3896215771956a763929474fc7493cb97270a781c`. 
There in the container running a mysql server. The mysql server store the data under The path `/srv/mcluster/mysql`.
I monitor the diskio throw the file "blkio.throttle.io_service_bytes".
There is a strange thing. If I insert data to the database. The file will change(which is as hoped). But if I use `dd if=/dev/zero of=/srv/mcluster/mysql/test_ljl bs=1M count=3072 oflag=dsync`, the file will remain unchanged.
Has anyone met this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! It's because that I use `nsenter` to get into the container. Instead that if I use `docker attach`, then the problem will be fixed.
Also I still find no answer for why this happened.